# Передача греческих топонимов

Tags: топонимика, транскрипция, греческий

Есть ли общие принципы передачи греческих топонимов на русском языке?

Нашел упоминания об Инструкции по передаче на картах географических названий Греции. — М., 1964, но её саму в электронном виде не смог нагуглить.

Может быть, кто-то может выложить её скан или дать ссылку на более актуальную методичку?

Дополнительная путаница возникает ещё и с тем, что на картах Генштаба, Яндекса, Гугла и OpenStreetMaps многие названия написаны по-разному. Кому из них верить?

Comment: Словарь Хорикова в конце дает не очень большой список топонимов, причем с вариациями (Эллиспонт / Геллеспонт, Айон-Орос / Агион-Орос, Кас(с)андра и пр.)

Answer (score 1):

Вот [официальный сайт Росреестра](https://rosreestr.ru/site/activity/zakonodatelstvo-rf-o-naimenovaniyakh-geograficheskikh-obektov/), на котором приводятся документы, определяющие законодательство Российской Федерации о наименованиях географических объектов. Среди них есть [инструкция 1964 года по передаче на картах географических названий Греции (pdf, не очень удобная для чтения — расшитая брошюра)](https://rosreestr.ru/upload/Doc/21-upr/instrukcii/20%20%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F.pdf).

Только, похоже, этой инструкци никто особо не следует…